# Как добавить делегаты на 1 или 3 параметра, если делегаты с 2-я параметрами уже есть?

Tags: c#, делегаты

В статье https://habr.com/ru/post/143925/ описывается применение делегатов для вызова методов +-/* (все с двумя переменными) у самописного калькулятора.

Как добавить методы с одной переменной (например, факториал числа) или с тремя переменными (например, определение объёма прямоугольного параллелепипеда на основе длин трёх рёбер: x * y * z)?

Comment: Ваши попытки самостоятельно решить вашу проблему?

Comment: Перегрузка метода `DefineOperation()` & добавление 2-x нужных словарей поможет вам.

Answer (score 0):

не изменяя программу добавить не получится. попробуй [паттерн Интерпретатор](https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/3.8.php)
если тебе нет необходимости сделать калькулятор чтобы он парсил строку и по ней считал, ты будешь "считать" кодом, то на этом можно и остановится
с парсером будет немного больше мороки (а вот там операторами ты будешь уже "жонглировать" - не забыть про приоритет операций, создавать операции для любого количества параметров, числа любого вида)